# Good login structure

Tags: php, mysql

Can you please give me some ideas for good php login structure.

I was thinking of something like this:

**Login page:**

***if logged in*** (checks if session exists) (

- redirect to front page.
- open session, save username, ID, rank to variables

)

***else***

- show login form
- check inputs comparing to database records
- save username, ID, rank to session variables
- show content.

**Other pages:**

***if logged in*** (checks if session exists) (

- open session, save username, ID, rank to variables.
- show user information

)

***else***

- redirect to login page, or stay on the page if unlogged access is
  allowed.

Comment: Pointless question. There are hundreds of examples online for instance: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

Comment: Not everyone is familiar with this kind of system/structure. I'm pretty sure OP is aware of online examples and just wanted to know if there is any alternatives. We all started here at some point.

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierBourgeois Yes, thank you :) I have seen many online examples, some of them are very advanced, including numerous other options i dont yet need for a simple login. I just wanted to be sure if my own example is good enough or may i be missing some important pieces. :)

Comment: Existence of a session as evidence of authentication???!!!! No! The session is *ALWAYS* going to exist - check if the username is set in the sesion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is pretty much about it.

Depending on the complexity of your application and your needs, you can also take a look at [authentification framworks](http://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=1), if you don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much the structure I use. Can't see any major problems.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how literally your pseudo structure is, you could possibly save yourself some work by simply redirecting unauthorized clients to the login page. Like this:

```
if( check_user_login() == false)
{
  header("Location: login.php");
  exit;  // make sure page parsing stops here
}

// the content for authorized clients
```